# Justification for squared L2 data and smoothness term as an error bound

Tags: normed-spaces, image-processing, triangle-inequality

I decided to cross-post this here too, since I believe this is on-topic and I expect an answer with an entirely different perspective: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/67852/justification-for-squared-l2-data-and-smoothness-term-as-an-error-bound

Often in variational methods (and not only) we have an energy that is of the form:
$$E(u) = \frac{1}{2}\|f-u\|^2_2 + \frac{\alpha}{2}\|\psi(u)\|^2_2,$$

where the first term is referred to as the data term, and the second as the smoothness term. I understand that the squared $L_2$ norm is especially appealing since it results in a simple expression when we are looking for the minimum. I am looking for the formal motivation for designing such an energy. More specifically, I would like to see it as resulting from some bound upon the actual error. Let $f$ be a degraded/noisy image of the original image $g$, and $u$ be the image that we are looking for. Is it possible for the above to be interpreted as a bound of $\|g-f\|^2_2$? Let us consider an even simpler problem (where $h$ is a sufficiently smoothed version of $f$):
$$E(u) = \frac{1}{2}\|f-u\|^2_2 + \frac{\alpha}{2}\|u-h\|^2_2$$
If I start from $\|g-f\|_2$ I can get the following bound:
$$\|u-g\| = \|u-f+f-g\| \leq \|u-f\| + \|f-g\|$$
$$\|u-g\| = \|u-h+h-g\| \leq \|u-h\| + \|h-g\|$$
Combining the two inequalities with some weight $\lambda \in [0,1]$ I get:
$$\|u-g\|\leq (1-\lambda)\|u-f\| + \lambda\|u-h\| + (1-\lambda)\|f-g\| + \lambda\|h-g\|$$
Since $f,g,h$ are fixed, the minimization is only over the first two terms:
$$\min_u (1-\lambda)\|u-f\| + \lambda\|u-h\|$$
And this can be rewritten through $\alpha$ by setting $\alpha = \frac{\lambda}{1-\lambda}$. My issue is that these are still not squared norms. If I try to square both sides, this results in a different minimization energy. The other way to get the squares involves writing out something of the form:
$$\|u-g\|^2 = \|(u-f) + (f-g)\|^2 = \|u-f\|^2 + \|f-g\|^2 - 2(u-f)\cdot(g-f) \\ \leq \|u-f\|^2 + \|f-g\|^2$$
The last inequality holds only when $(u-f)\cdot(g-f) \geq 0$ though. Said otherwise, the angle between $(u-f)$ and $(g-f)$ needs to be smaller than 90 degrees which is not something that can be guaranteed I believe.
A looser bound is:
$$\|u-g\|^2 \leq \|u-f\|^2 + \|f-g\|^2 + 2\|u-f\|\|f-g\|,$$
but it also involves non-squared terms.

Here's something else I noticed about the non-squared energy:

$$\alpha\|u-f\| + \beta\|u-h\|, \alpha, \beta > 0$$

will always have as solutions $u=f$ or $u=h$ for $\alpha<\beta$ respectively $\alpha>\beta$. When $\alpha=\beta$ any solution of the form $(1-\lambda)f + \lambda h$ is admissible. It is thus clear that the above is not very interesting as a minimization energy.

Comment: Not what you're asking for, but there's a Bayesian perspective where we are doing maximum a posteriori (MAP) estimation.

Comment: @littleO I got a similar answer over at the signal processing stack, so I guess that is the standard way to motivate it. And yes, I was looking for a justification through an error bound (without assumptions on the noise), but I guess that is not something standard. If anything the bound that I have results in a very boring energy (either $u=f$ or $u=h$ as a solution).

Comment: You could consider the constrained problem of minimizing $(1/2) \| u. - f \|^2$ subject to the constraint that $\| \Psi(u) \|^2 \leq \epsilon$. The optimization variable is $u$. By a Lagrange multiplier theorem, there exists a Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$ such that any minimizer for this constrained problem is also a minimizer for the unconstrained problem of minimizing $(1/2) \| u - f \|^2 + \lambda \| \Psi(u) \|^2$.

Comment: @littleO I get that part. What I am missing is a connection between $\|u-g\|$ and the above energy ($g$ is the reference image from which $f$ is produced after the introduction of noise etc). Since ideally we want to show that minimizing the proposed energy, also minimizes $\|u-g\|$, even if under some assumptions on the degradation of $f$. I have seen the above energy used even for non-Gaussian noise image degradation, so I assumed that there was some general justification for that. But the more I look into it, the more it seems like this energy cannot be the result of a general bound.